# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol (using static structure)

Tags: visual-c++

I defined some static variable in main header of my program like:

```
TenerWinDlg.h

...
static struct Asal
{
CString m_sAme;
float m_fAtion;
double m_dArice;
}m_sAntp[20];
static int m_iNutors;
static double m_dItion;
...
```

and initialize them in main file like:

```
TenderWinDlg.cpp

...
struct CTenderWinDlg::Asal m_sAntp[20]={NULL, 0, 0};
int CTenderWinDlg::m_Nutors=0;
double CTenderWinDlg::m_dItion=0;
...
```

I can compile and run this without any error. everything is OK til I want to use them in some other dialogs. I can use "int" and "double" static variable (i.e. m_iNutors & m_dItion) simply without any error.but, when I want to use the static structre* I confront with this error:

```
Dialog3.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static struct CTenderWinDlg::Asal *        CTenderWinDlg::m_sAntp" (?m_sAntp@CTenderWinDlg@@2PAUAsal@1@A)
```

The interesting thing is that if I delete the "static" from declaration of structure, the error disappears. but without static variable, I'm not be able to save and hold my data.it would be appreciated if you hellp me.
in short, I want to use a static structure to save and hold the name, and specification of 20 participants.

Comment: Please try to create a [mre], then [edit] your question to show it. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: By the way, the error message mentions `static struct CTenderWinDlg::Asal *CTenderWinDlg::m_sAntp`, which doesn't match the code you show. Again, please create a [mre] to show us. Preferably one we can copy-paste the test ourselves.